# Multivariable Chain Rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Does anyone know how to use the multivariable chain rule to solve the following problem?

> If $G(x^2+y^2, x+y)=(7x+3y, x+5\,y)$, knowing that $G:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, find $(G^{-1})'(24,8)$

Comment: Yes.  What have you tried?  Would it help to know that $G^{-1}(24,8) = (3,1)$?

Comment: $G^{-1}(24,8)=(3,1)$? I have $G^{-1}(24,8)=(10,4)$.

Comment: I Took the derivative of both sides, and obtained the following: $G'(x^2+y^2,x+y)\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
 2x&2y \\ 
 1&1 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 7&3 \\ 
 1&5 
\end{bmatrix}$ @EricTowers, but i have no idea how i should do next

Comment: @MarioG:  Is correct.  I found the inverse in terms of $x$ and $y$ and didn't conflate them into the arguments of $G$.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $(x,y)\mapsto(7x+3y,x+5y)$, observe
$$G^{-1}\circ f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,x+y)$$
 applying Chain Rule it follows
\begin{align}
DG^{-1}[f(x,y)]Df(x,y)&=\begin{bmatrix}2x&2y\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\\
DG^{-1}[f(x,y)]\begin{bmatrix}7&3\\1&5\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}2x&2y\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Then, putting $x=3,y=1$ and since $f(3,1)=(24,8)$ we get
\begin{align}
DG^{-1}(24,8)\begin{bmatrix}7&3\\1&5\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}6&2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\\
DG^{-1}(24,8)&=\begin{bmatrix}6&2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}7&3\\1&5\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}6&2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{5}{32}&-\frac{3}{32}\\-\frac{1}{32}&\frac{7}{32}\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{7}{8}&-\frac{1}{8}\\\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{8}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}